# Why won't window.btoa work on – ” characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm converting a string to BASE64 as shown in the code below...

```
var str = "Hello World";
var enc = window.btoa(str);
```

This yields `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=`. However if I add these characters `– ”` such as the code shown below, the conversion doesn't happen. What is the reason behind this? Thank you so much.

```
var str = "Hello – World”";
var enc = window.btoa(str);
```

Comment: Hi! I edited the post. Thank you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`btoa` is an exotic function in that [it requires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#Syntax) a "Binary String", i.e. it's a `String` datatype but every "letter" doesn't represent a letter but a byte. As such, you can't have any "letters" with Unicode codepoints above 0xFF (charcode 255), such as used by your em dash and "fancy" quote symbol.

You'll either have to uri encode the data first, making it safe:

```js
> var str = `Hello – World`;
> window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(str));
"SGVsbG8lMjAlRTIlODAlOTMlMjBXb3JsZA=="
```

And then remember to decode it again when unpacking yourself:

```js
> var base64= "SGVsbG8lMjAlRTIlODAlOTMlMjBXb3JsZA==";
> decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64));
"Hello – World"
```

Or rely on targets that automatically apply URI decoding like `href` attributes (`a`, `link`, etc).

However, if your target doesn't (your own code, or `src` attributes on `img`, `script`, etc.) then you'll need to turn your string into a new string that conforms to single byte packing. This is explicitly called out over on [the MDN for base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64#the_unicode_problem), with their solution being:

```js
function base64(data) {
  const bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(data);
  const binString = String.fromCodePoint(...bytes);
  return btoa(binString);
}
```

with the equivalent decoder:

```js
function decode64(base64) {
  const binString = atob(base64);
  const bytes = Uint8Array.from(binString, (m) => m.codePointAt(0));
  return new TextDecoder().decode(bytes);
}
```

You'll need the `decode64` if you want to unpack things in your own code, but the `base64` function will yield a converted string that will work when put into a data-url (e.g. `data:text/javascript;base64,${base64text}`);

Comment: I think it was the first guy who answered wrong. I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote but URL encoding is not a very convenient way to workaround that issue

Comment: quite a lot more convenient than the traditional method involving `charCodeAt()` though .

Comment: But the base64 encoding of this exact input is `SGVsbG8g4oCTIFdvcmxk4oCd` not `SGVsbG8lMjAlRTIlODAlOTMlMjBXb3JsZA` so this is not the base64 representation of the input. You can't share it with anything that expects a true base64, for instance if you type `data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8lMjAlRTIlODAlOTMlMjBXb3JsZA` in your address bar it won't work.

Comment: @Kaiido: This exact input has no base64 encoding, because base64 is not defined on Unicode strings, but byte streams. Only a string’s representation in a particular encoding has a base64 encoding, and the choice of encoding is arbitrary. It may be UTF-8, or it may be URL-encoded UTF-8; it only matters that endpoints agree on the encoding/decoding steps.

Comment: @user3840170 true, now how many endpoints will expect URL encoding vs UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the character `”` lies outside of Latin1 range.

For this you can use `unescape` (now deprecated)

```js
var str = "Hello – World”";
var enc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));

alert(enc);
```

And to decode:

```js
var encStr = "SGVsbG8g4oCTIFdvcmxk4oCd";
var dec = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(encStr)))

alert(dec);
```

Comment: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape, it's not a good idea to rely on `unescape` at all - just encode, and then decode after `atob`

Answer (score 0):

The most bullet proof way is to work on binary data directly.

For this, you can encode your string to an `ArrayBuffer` object representing the UTF-8 version of your string.

Then a `FileReader` instance will be able to give you the base64 quite easily.

```js
var str = "Hello – World”";
var buf = new TextEncoder().encode( str );
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = evt => { console.log( reader.result.split(',')[1] ); };
reader.readAsDataURL( new Blob([buf]) );
```

And since the `Blob()` constructor does automagically encode `DOMString` instances to UTF-8, we could even get rid of the `TextEncoder` object:

```js
var str = "Hello – World”";
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = evt => { console.log( reader.result.split(',')[1] ); };
reader.readAsDataURL( new Blob([str]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately owes to a deficiency in the JavaScript type system.

JavaScript strings are strings of *16-bit* code units, which are customarily interpreted as UTF-16. The Base64 encoding is a method of transforming an *8-bit* byte stream into a string of digits, by taking each three bytes and mapping them into four digits, each covering 6 bits: 3 × 8 = 4 × 6. As we see, this is crucially dependent on the bit width of each symbol.

At the time the `btoa` function was defined, JavaScript had no type for 8-bit byte streams, so the API was defined to take the ordinary 16-bit string type as input, with the restriction that each code unit was supposed to be confined to the range [U+0000, U+00FF]; when encoded into ISO-8859-1, such a string would reproduce the intended byte stream exactly.

The character `–` is U+2013, while `”` is U+201D; neither of those characters fits into the above-mentioned range, so the function rejects it.

If you want to convert Unicode text into Base64, you need to pick a character encoding and convert it into a byte string first, and encode *that*. Asking for a Base64 encoding of a Unicode string itself is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

i was struggled with this one too. so i made up two functions.

```
function TtB64(txt){
return btoa(new TextEncoder().encode(txt).join(' '))
```

};

```
function TfB64(txt){
return new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(atob(txt).split(' ').map(x => x=parseInt(x))))
```

};

the first one any text to base 64, and the second one from base 64 to text.

Answer (score -1):

why so complicated?

```
btoa(new TextEncoder().encode("Hello – World”").join(''))
```

will do..

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and explain how it helps to solve the problem. If this post is perceived as an unexplained code-only blurp its chances for appreciation are reduced.